# WebSoket и Promise || Иммитация Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, websocket, promise

Решил отказаться от Ajax  и все взаимодействие с сервером провожу через вебсокеты.

Все стандартно: получаю, отправляю запросы. Однако, столкнулся с таким неудобством: я не могу, как при использовании Ajax, обработать ответ сервера в том же месте кода, в котором и был отправлен запрос. Приходится отправлять сообщение и где-то там, в структуре проекта, создавать обработчик в ответ на это сообщение, в котором мне надо просто вывести alert (условно)

По факту, в некоторых случаях запись типа `ws.send(message).then()....` мне бы идеально подошла, но как я понимаю с вебсокетами так не получится. 
Или получится?

**UPDT:**
В ожидании внимания к вопросу набросал такой класс.

```
`class WS {
  constructor(wsAddr) {
    this.$ws = new WebSocket(wsAddr);
  }
    get(message){
        const {type} = message;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
            this.$ws.send(JSON.stringify(message));
            this.$ws.addEventListener('message', (res)=>{
                const data = JSON.parse(res.data);
                if (data.type === type){
                    resolve(data)
                }
            });
        })
    }
};`
```

Код работает, мою задачу выполняет. Теперь я могу писать:
`ws.get().then(res)....`

Но возникают всякие вопросы: не превышу ли я какой-нибудь лимит по слушателям? Что будет если в момент запроса придет другое сообщение от сервера? и другие вопросы, о которых я и не подозреваю

Comment: посмотри лучше в сторону rxjs

Comment: @Grundy вы имеете в виду [этот npm пакет](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs)? Тогда не понимаю связи. @Дмытрык, по вашей проблеме - нужно пересмотреть подход к написанию приложения. AJAX - хорош в разовых запросах. Вебсокеты - это "поток". Нужно сделать свой обработчик сообщений и через события "раскидывать" по приложению. Приходит сообщение `{ "type": "chat", "message": "..." }` - кидаете событие "чат". Тот, кто подписался - получает его. Тогда нужен будет только один вебсокет.

Comment: @TotalPusher, Вы употребили правильный термин "разовый". У меня есть глобальный обработчик. Однако, при обработке разового запроса, который идет из одного единственного компонента, я почувствовал неудобство, придерживаясь старого принципа. Для этого мне надо создать отдельный файл, подключить его и т.д. и т.п. А с промисом я могу обработать ответ в том же месте, где и делал запрос.

Comment: К сожалению, нет серебряной пули. В каких-то сценариях AJAX действительно удобнее.В других удобнее вебсокеты. Если решили все делать на вебсокетах, то будете страдать от излишнего кода на единичных запросах. А если, заходите сделать что-то вроде `Promise.all` или запуск последовательных запросов, то будет совсем боль :)

Comment: @TotalPusher, да, можно и этот. Связь в том, что Promise - это одноразовый объект, перевести в состояние resolve/reject можно только один раз, в отличии от Observable. И так как событие message может происходить больше одного раза - Promise тут совсем не подойдет

Comment: @Дмытрык, сделайте cвою либу, тогда сможете `ws.get().then(res)`. `get("get-cart-items", {...})` возвращает промис, который добавляет `resolve` и `reject` в свою очередь (массив). Когда приходит `ws.onmessage`, происходит его разбор `JSON.parse`. Определяется тип - "get-cart-items". Очередь ищется по этому типу и вызываются соответствующие `resolve`. Это если не хотите событийную модель использовать.